# Science fiction miniseries involving a team of teenagers on a spaceship with a mainframe named Priscilla

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

It was a miniseries (hope so), possibly Disney, but I am not sure. It aired in Russia around 1992-1996. It was in color, so possibly was filmed in the 60s-80s.

A team of teenagers were on a spaceship travelling somewhere in space. The only name I remember is Priscilla - their mainframe. They suddenly found an old radio signal from Earth and one of the boys liked it and gave the order "Priscilla, follow the wave". Later, they saved a guy from a damaged ship and he taught them some battle and survival techniques.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Earth Star Voyager is much asked about: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Earth+Star+Voyager

Comment: Clearly a show that made an impression on a lot of people...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[Earth Star Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)*** (1988), a three-hour long, two-part pilot for a series that was ultimately never picked up.

The [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/EarthStarVoyager) page mentions that it was originally aired on ABC's *The Disney Sunday Movie*:

> ***Earth☆Star Voyager* is a Pilot Movie that originally aired as a 2-part miniseries on ABC's *The Disney Sunday Movie* in January 1988.** It focuses on a group of over-achieving young people from a late 21st century Crapsack Earth as they trek through the stars to find a new home for the human race. Along the way, the crew has to deal with the usual dangers of TV space travel, along with the drama and awkwardness typical of being a teenager or a young adult on television.

In the year 2088, the Earth's deteriorating ecology is making the planet increasingly uninhabitable. An interstellar spacecraft named the Earth Star Voyager, equipped with a sentient supercomputer named Priscilla, is being sent to distant planet to see if it'd make a suitable new home for the human race. Since the journey there and back is expected to take 26 years, almost the entire crew selected for the mission are in their teens or early twenties, with the exception of Captain Forbes. However, Forbes is killed during an apparent mishap not long after departure, forcing his 21-year-old second-in-command, Jonathan Hayes, to take over.

Not long after that, the ship docks with an abandoned space station, where the crew encounters Jake Brown, the captain of an Earth ship that went missing six years earlier. He's brought aboard the Earth Star Voyager and becomes a useful member of the crew, acting as a mentor of sorts to some of  the other officers, helping them in fights, and building a rail gun for the ship.

Much later in the story, Priscilla picks up some old radio waves that were broadcast on Earth in the twentieth century. One of the officers likes one of the songs that is briefly heard, and orders Priscilla to alter course to "follow that song" so he can continue listening to it a while longer.

You can view the scene where Captain Brown is brought aboard the Earth Star Voyager at around the 39:41 mark in the video below. You can view the scene where Priscilla picks up the old radio signals at around the 1:53:59 mark. The line "Priscilla, follow that song" is spoken at around the 1:56:10 mark.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is it. Would not find it without you. It was aired under a different title and sequence of the episodes was changed for some reasons. Bring back my childhood back. Will watch it with original sound and woices.